# How to make this SQL query using IN (with many numeric IDs) more efficient?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, query-optimization

I've been waiting over an hour already for this query, so I know I'm probably doing something wrong. Is there efficient  way to tailor this query: ?

```
select RespondentID, MIN(SessionID) as 'SID'
from BIG_Sessions (nolock)
where RespondentID in (
1418283,
1419863,
1421188,
1422101,
1431384,
1435526,
1437284,
1441394,
/* etc etc THOUSANDS */
1579244 )
    and EntryDate between
    '07-11-2011' and '07-31-2012'
GROUP BY RespondentID
```

I kknow that my date range is pretty big, but I can't change that part (the dates are spread all over) .

Also, the reason for `MIN(SessionID)` is because otherwise we get many SessionID's for each Respondent, and one suffices(it's taking MIN on an alphanumeric ID like ach2a23a-adhsdx123... and getting the first alphabetically)

Thanks

Comment: Two questions:

1.)  What database engine are you using?  2.)  Any indexes present on RespondentID?  What kind of indexes?  (e.g., btree or hash?)

Comment: Do you have an index on RespondentID?

Comment: @Greg - No, but there is an index on EntryDate. I guess it doesn't matter much if there's only one index right? i.e., the chain is strong as weakest-link  ? I better go study indexes!

Comment: @JuliusDavies - I'm using SQL Server Database Engine (Microsoft) . Or is ther a specific version I can see?

Comment: FYI: The range of dates is irrelevant to the performance of your query other than as it relates to how many rows are returned. Also, the MIN() operation isn't significant in terms of perormance impact.

Comment: It would help to know where you are getting the big list of RecipientIDs. If there is any way to join to that source instead of serializing it out to a list of integers you would be better off.

Comment: @JohnFx - Hmm that's an interesting fact. I gotta figure that out, it's a bit counterintuitive I think. Thanks much!

Comment: @JohnFx - As of now it's from an Excel spreadsheet. So the original query used PIVOT and i'm not sure of how to incorporate the IN query with it.. but I definitely will study what you suggest

Comment: Best guess from the info provided would be to index RespondentID. I'm guessing that it would be more unique than the date that you currently index. Keep in mind the cost of adding an index whenever an insert/update/delete is called on the table though.

Comment: In that case, just import the excel spreadsheet into a table and join on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Put your thousands of numbers in a temporary table.
2. Index the number field in that table.
3. **Index the RespondentID field in BIG_SESSIONS**
4. Join the two tables

eg:

```
select RespondentID, MIN(SessionID) as 'SID' 
from BIG_Sessions (nolock) 
    inner join RespondentsFilterTable 
        on BIG_SESSIONS.RespondentID = RespondentsFilterTable.RespondentID
where EntryDate between '07-11-2011' and '07-31-2012' 
GROUP BY BIG_Sessions.RespondentID
```

You could add indexes to EntryDate and SessionID as well, but if you're adding to big_sessions frequently, this could be counter productive elsewhere

In general, you can can get hints of how performance of a query can be improved by studying the estimated (or if possible actual) execution plans.

Comment: Note: This is only going to help if you run a query against the same list of items over and over. If this is a one off (for that list) your query will be just as fast if you do it inline. The problem is building and indexing that table will offset the gains from any one run, so unless you are re-using that table it isn't worth it.

Comment: @JohnFx I'd test that first. The RDBMS may spend less time indexing the temp table than not having an index to use.

Comment: I disagree simply based on what needs to happen. To create an index you need to to a table scan, which is exactly the slow operation the OP is trying to avoid. Query + Table Scan will never be less than Query +  Populate Table + Table Scan + write index.

Comment: @JohnFx actually if the #temp table just has an int column, and/or it's a small subset of the base table, it may be a far cheaper scan than the one required in the join (the table may be very wide).

Answer (score 1):

If the smallest and largest ids in the IN statement are known beforehands and depending on how many ids are in the table then adding a `respondedID > [smallest_known_id-1] AND respondedID < [largest_known_id+1]` prior to the IN statement would help limiting the problem

Comment: "prior to" implies that the query is processed in some defined order. Depending on a variety of factors the query won't necessarily be processed in the order it's written (e.g. left to right), though this is a common myth.

Comment: thanks, I tend to place the least demanding criteria before most complex ones as good practice just to be covered against any case. Will it get processed in the way it's written in the specific case though?

Comment: There's no way to know. Often the criteria are processed in order, but there are no guarantees. And even if you observe something once, it doesn't necessarily mean that is the plan that will always be used for the same query.